# Difference list with (-)/2 operator

Tags: prolog, difference-lists

I am currently taking a Prolog course.

I'm familiar with the `[A|B]` notation of lists in Prolog, but the teacher shows that `[a,b,c|X]-X` is also a valid way of having a list, where we have a reference to the tail of the list. When I try it out with Swi-Prolog however, I receive the following error: `ERROR: Undefined procedure: (-)/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)`.

Is the (-)/2 operator just defined in standard Prolog but not in Swi-Prolog or am I missing something ?

Comment: The minus is only used with an argument Much better is to use two different arguments.

Comment: You should be able to use `[a,b,c|X]-X` in SWI Prolog as well. The `-` carries no special meaning to Prolog in this context. It's just an operator. If you are describing an error, you need to show the code that generated the  error or the error is meaningless to anyone reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This structure is called difference list. (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Difference_Lists)

Probably you used '-' wrong. Let's consider append predicate on difference lists:

```
app(X-Y, Y-Z, X-Z).
```

You can test it like this (after compiling file having this predicate):

```
?- app([1,2,3|A]-A, [4, 5|B]-B, C).
```

[1,2,3|A]-A can be considered as [1,2,3] and [4, 5|B]-B can be considered as [4,5], so having output:

```
A = [4, 5|B],
C = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5|B]-B.
```

You can see, that C became [1, 2, 3, 4, 5|B]-B that can be considered as [1,2,3,4,5].

Little visualization of what's going on there:

```
 <-------------------X--------------------->
               <-------------Y------------->
                              <-----Z------>
||............||.............||............||   <- List
 <--- X-Y ----><---- Y-Z ---->
 <---------- X-Z ------------>
```

Comment: *`[1,2,3|A]-A` is just `[1,2,3]`* is not just confusing, but it's incorrect. These are two different terms.

Answer (score 2):

`[a,b,c|X]-X` is the same as `'-'([a,b,c|X],X)`. It is just a compound term, used as data.

You used it as a callable goal, which it is not.

You don't call such terms, you manipulate them, use them as arguments to your predicates expressing relationships between them.